# Group objects inside the nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have 2 arrays inside another array. Inside these arrays there are objects and I want to group them by the object key.

*parent array contains n array*

```
[array_1, array_2]
```

Like I said, inside these arrays there is also an array filled with objects

*array 1*

```
taskTypeList: Array(7)
0: TaskType {Key: 313, Value: "R/I", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 1}
1: TaskType {Key: 312, Value: "MEL", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 2}
2: TaskType {Key: 311, Value: "SGH", IsDisabled: false, Duration: 9}
3: TaskType {Key: 309, Value: "LOC", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 4}
4: TaskType {Key: 485, Value: "TT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 5}
5: TaskType {Key: 310, Value: "FOT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 6}
6: TaskType {Key: 314, Value: "TS", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 7}
```

*array 2*

```
taskTypeList: Array(7)
0: TaskType {Key: 313, Value: "R/I", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 1}
1: TaskType {Key: 312, Value: "MEL", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 2}
2: TaskType {Key: 311, Value: "SGH", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 3}
3: TaskType {Key: 309, Value: "LOC", IsDisabled: false, Duration: 6}
4: TaskType {Key: 485, Value: "TT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 5}
5: TaskType {Key: 310, Value: "FOT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 6}
6: TaskType {Key: 314, Value: "TS", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 7}
```

I want to group these arrays by their keys. Result should be like this:

```
0:
309: [TaskType,TaskType]
310: [TaskType,TaskType]
311: [TaskType,TaskType]
312: [TaskType,TaskType]
313: [TaskType,TaskType]
314: [TaskType,TaskType]
485: [TaskType,TaskType]
```

How can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `spread` operator to concat arrays and then use `reduce` method to group by keys

```js
let array1 = [
 {Key: 313, Value: "R/I", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 1},
 {Key: 312, Value: "MEL", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 2},
 {Key: 311, Value: "SGH", IsDisabled: false, Duration: 9},
 {Key: 309, Value: "LOC", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 4},
 {Key: 485, Value: "TT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 5},
 {Key: 310, Value: "FOT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 6},
 {Key: 314, Value: "TS", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 7}
]

let array2 = [
 {Key: 313, Value: "R/I", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 1},
 {Key: 312, Value: "MEL", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 2},
 {Key: 311, Value: "SGH", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 3},
 {Key: 309, Value: "LOC", IsDisabled: false, Duration: 6},
 {Key: 485, Value: "TT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 5},
 {Key: 310, Value: "FOT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 6},
 {Key: 314, Value: "TS", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 7}
];

let container = [...array1, ...array2];
let result = container.reduce((acc, c) => ((acc[c.Key] = (acc[c.Key] || [])).push(c), acc),{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to merge the arrays together first and key by each Key value:

```js
var parentArray = [
  [{
      Key: 313,
      Value: "R/I",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 1
    },
    {
      Key: 312,
      Value: "MEL",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 2
    },
    {
      Key: 311,
      Value: "SGH",
      IsDisabled: false,
      Duration: 9
    },
    {
      Key: 309,
      Value: "LOC",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 4
    },
    {
      Key: 485,
      Value: "TT",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 5
    },
    {
      Key: 310,
      Value: "FOT",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 6
    },
    {
      Key: 314,
      Value: "TS",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 7
    }
  ],

  [{
      Key: 313,
      Value: "R/I",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 1
    },
    {
      Key: 312,
      Value: "MEL",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 2
    },
    {
      Key: 311,
      Value: "SGH",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 3
    },
    {
      Key: 309,
      Value: "LOC",
      IsDisabled: false,
      Duration: 6
    },
    {
      Key: 485,
      Value: "TT",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 5
    },
    {
      Key: 310,
      Value: "FOT",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 6
    },
    {
      Key: 314,
      Value: "TS",
      IsDisabled: true,
      Duration: 7
    }
  ]
];

var allTasks = [].concat.apply([], parentArray);
var grouped = {};
for (var i = 0, len = allTasks.length; i < len; i++) {
  var item = allTasks[i];  
  grouped[item["Key"]] = grouped[item["Key"]] || [];
  grouped[item["Key"]].push(item);
};

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following procedure.

1. Concatenate the two arrays
2. Create a new array by parsing the concatenated array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      var arr1 = [
        {TaskType : {Key: 313, Value: "R/I", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 1}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 312, Value: "MEL", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 2}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 311, Value: "SGH", IsDisabled: false, Duration: 9}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 309, Value: "LOC", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 4}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 485, Value: "TT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 5}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 310, Value: "FOT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 6}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 314, Value: "TS", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 7}}
      ];
      var arr2 = [
        {TaskType : {Key: 313, Value: "R/I", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 1}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 312, Value: "MEL", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 2}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 311, Value: "SGH", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 3}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 309, Value: "LOC", IsDisabled: false, Duration: 6}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 485, Value: "TT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 5}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 310, Value: "FOT", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 6}},
        {TaskType : {Key: 314, Value: "TS", IsDisabled: true, Duration: 7}},
      ];
      var combinedArr = [];
      var joinedArray = arr1.concat(arr2);
      joinedArray.forEach(item => {
        if(combinedArr[item.TaskType.Key]){
          combinedArr[item.TaskType.Key].push(item)
        }
        else {
          combinedArr[item.TaskType.Key] = [];
          combinedArr[item.TaskType.Key].push(item)
        }
      });
      console.log(combinedArr);
      </script>
  </head>
</html>
```